# How to stop a silverlight OOB application from bouncing on the Mac?

Tags: silverlight, macos

I am currently working on a silverlight application that will have to be cross platform. This means that it has to have mac support.

The problem however is that when the application is launched out of browser on a mac, and you try to swipe up/down(two-finger gesture scroll) it bounces in the silverlight window.

Is there any way to stop that from happening?

For an example:
Go to http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html, install it on your mac. Then try to swipe up and down.

Comment: Swipe is typically used as a verb that applies to touch devices.  I'm not sure how it would apply to a Mac.  What does it mean in reference to a Mac?  Also, this is not an OOB example.

Comment: What I mean with swipe, is scrolling using two fingers (gesture), I'll edit my post for that. And you should be able to install it by right-clicking inside the example and click install. This should put a icon on your desktop, which will launch it OOB.

Comment: Do you have any other way of scrolling other than the swipe gesture?  Does it happen for those methods also?  What kind of options do the gestures have?  Perhaps it has something to do with sensitivity or an over scroll option?  Sorry, I'm not a mac person, but I'll help if I can.

Comment: No it's only for the gesture based scrolling. Scrolling with a mouse wheels works just fine